# Simple working example to override default visual style of a button in wpf

Tags: wpf, vb.net, button

I want to create custom visual style for my buttons.
I need a simple working example of how to override default visual style of a button. As well as a simple explanation of how to apply it.
I want to get something working, so I can start from there and experiment my way further.

I've tried to add a new recourse dictionary as follows:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Style x:Key="mstyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
</Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

after that I've created some new button in runtime and tried to apply this style to it:

```
    Dim MyButton As New Button
    Dim st As New Style
    st = Application.Current.FindResource("mstyle")
    MyButton.Style = st
```

When I try to run this, I get an error that the recourse 'mstyle' could not be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't in most cases need any code behind to do that all what you need is to define a custom style that target your button in the resource dictionary or in the window resource here an example :

```
 <Style x:Key="DarkStyleButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#373737" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border CornerRadius="4" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="MyContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#E59400" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

- first set the value for the properties you want to customize,
- then set the button template and don't forget to add the
  ContentPresenter that will hold the button content
- finally define triggers to handle the mouse over, click and what ever
  else you want to set a custom look when it triggers (for example the
  desable/enabled )

To use that style here how

```
 <Button  x:Name="BrowseButton" Margin="5"  Style="{StaticResource DarkStyleButton}" ToolTip="tooltip about the button">
                    <Button.Content>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="../BrowseImage.png"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Browse" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button.Content>
                </Button>
```

Comment: Hmm. I'm doing something wrong. I've opened a new solution. I've added a new recourse dictionary, and copied in your example. After that I copied the button definition in the xaml of the main window. The button is generated, but with a default style and the `Style="{StaticResource DarkStyleButton}"` is highlighted as an error that says: "The recourse "DarkStyleButton" could not be resolved."

Comment: did you add the resource dico to the current window/Page resource : <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/ResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>